# How to see HTML path file in inspect element?

Tags: html

Is it possible to see HTML path in inspect element ?
I only see Css , Javascript etc

Thanks

Comment: @MisterJojo — Node.js doesn’t have an element inspector

Comment: What does "HTML path" mean? The [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath)?

Comment: FWIW, the html on a page doesn't even need to come from an actual .html file, it may just be rendered by code.

Answer (score 2):

No.

There’s no HTML element or attribute that implicitly contains information about the location the document was loaded from.

CSS and JS locations show up there because the HTML document has to state where to load its dependancies from.

[The `location` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) has that information, but it isn’t part of the DOM.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin.. is there any other way to do that?